# Why does snmpget output give strange numbers as the result (unsigned32?)

Tags: bash, snmp, unsigned

Reallly strange to me but here is the problem.

If I use an SNMP client such as ManageEngineMibBrowser to query the appliance I get what look like reasonable Numbers:

```
dpStatusMemoryStatusUsage.0 97
dpStatusMemoryStatusTotalMemory.0 33015552
dpStatusMemoryStatusUsedMemory.0 31928048
dpStatusMemoryStatusFreeMemory.0 1087504
dpStatusMemoryStatusReqMemory.0 4294967295
dpStatusMemoryStatusXG4Usage.0 4294967295
dpStatusMemoryStatusHoldMemory.0 4294967295
```

How do I justify Reasonable? Well simple maths shows that if TotalMemory is 3301552 and UsedMemory is 31928048 Then a percentage of 97% for Usage seems right (plus I double checked with the GUI :)

Now then I run the same commands on the same using snmpget on Linux and get the following (they are OIDS but in the same order as above):

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.1.0 = Gauge32: 36
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.2.0 = Gauge32: 99197400
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.3.0 = Gauge32: 36004164
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.4.0 = Gauge32: 63193236
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.5.0 = Gauge32: 4294967295
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.6.0 = Gauge32: 4294967295
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.7.0 = Gauge32: 4294967295
```

As you can see they are all of the type Gauge32.... but the first 4 values are totally different! Do I need to do some kind of conversion? If so, Why are the first 4 different and the last 3 not when they are all of the same type? Am I being really dumb? :)

Comment: Can you provide net-snmp symbolic (textual) form? Should be something vaguely like 
cd <directory with your MIBs> ;  snmpwalk  -M +.  -m +ALL  -v 2c -c  public <your device ipaddress>  DATAPOWER-STATUS-MIB::dpStatus

Comment: Also use net-snmp snmptranslate to check you have right OIDs  ... something like  ... snmptranslate  -M +.  -m +ALL  -On  DATAPOWER-STATUS-MIB::dpStatusMemoryStatusUsage